# How to publish dotnet core tests with jenkins pipeline?

Tags: .net, jenkins, .net-core, nunit, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to publish test result with jenkins-pipeline,

Using this pipeline script I manage to get the build done and produce the "xml" outputs:

```
node {
stage 'Checkout'
    checkout scm

stage 'Build'
    bat "\"C:/Program Files/dotnet/dotnet.exe\" restore \"${workspace}/MyProg.sln\""
    bat "\"C:/Program Files/dotnet/dotnet.exe\" build \"${workspace}/MyProg.sln\""

stage 'UnitTests'
    bat returnStatus: true, script: "\"C:/Program Files/dotnet/dotnet.exe\" test \"${workspace}/MyProg.sln\" --logger \"trx;LogFileName=unit_tests.xml\" --no-build"
    nunit testResultsPattern: 'Tests\\*Test*\\TestResults\\unit_tests.xml'
}
```

But in the "UnitTest" stage I get this error:

> " Publish NUnit test result report    Could not read the XSL XML file.
>   Please report this issue to the plugin author "

When I'm using the "normal" steps build (without the pipline framework) the testing get published.
Using:

- DotNet Core 2.0
- Jenkins 2.111
- NUnit Plugin 0.23

Attaching one of the XML :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestRun id="201fdc5c-9a47-461b-a56c-1aec8778053d" name="golano1@VM-CCT-BUILD3 2018-03-28 17:36:50" runUser="CORP\golano1" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
  <Times creation="2018-03-28T17:36:50.5380380+03:00" queuing="2018-03-28T17:36:50.5380497+03:00" start="2018-03-28T17:36:38.1418862+03:00" finish="2018-03-28T17:36:55.6498820+03:00" />
  <TestSettings name="default" id="3e9b0993-3888-4428-bd08-e217e3b54831">
    <Deployment runDeploymentRoot="golano1_VM-CCT-BUILD3 2018-03-28 17_36_50" />
  </TestSettings>
  <Results>
    <UnitTestResult executionId="77a19978-2bbb-4bcb-afaa-d5be4384e0d1" testId="a08b2ec5-a68d-434b-a35f-6c65159eee8f" testName="TestSentinalOneBigFile_Failed" computerName="VM-CCT-BUILD3" duration="00:00:05.0340000" startTime="2018-03-28T17:36:45.0000000+03:00" endTime="2018-03-28T17:36:50.0000000+03:00" testType="13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b" outcome="Passed" testListId="8c84fa94-04c1-424b-9868-57a2d4851a1d" relativeResultsDirectory="77a19978-2bbb-4bcb-afaa-d5be4384e0d1" />
    <UnitTestResult executionId="49fb4bd0-d650-4ed4-b0f2-40241b138f40" testId="15590544-6d25-4b07-9736-91fc3089eb1d" testName="TestSentinalOneFullScanOfSingleFile_Success" computerName="VM-CCT-BUILD3" duration="00:00:05.0130000" startTime="2018-03-28T17:36:50.0000000+03:00" endTime="2018-03-28T17:36:55.0000000+03:00" testType="13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b" outcome="Passed" testListId="8c84fa94-04c1-424b-9868-57a2d4851a1d" relativeResultsDirectory="49fb4bd0-d650-4ed4-b0f2-40241b138f40" />
  </Results>
  <TestDefinitions>
    <UnitTest name="TestSentinalOneBigFile_Failed" storage="c:\jenkins\workspace\testfolder\pg_branchbuild\tests\sentinalonetests\bin\debug\netcoreapp2.0\sentinalonetests.dll" id="a08b2ec5-a68d-434b-a35f-6c65159eee8f">
      <Execution id="77a19978-2bbb-4bcb-afaa-d5be4384e0d1" />
      <TestMethod codeBase="C:\Jenkins\workspace\TestFolder\PG_BranchBuild\Tests\SentinaloneTests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\SentinaloneTests.dll" executorUriOfAdapter="executor://nunit3testexecutor/" className="SentinaloneTests.SentinaloneEngineConnectorTest" name="TestSentinalOneBigFile_Failed" />
    </UnitTest>
    <UnitTest name="TestSentinalOneFullScanOfSingleFile_Success" storage="c:\jenkins\workspace\testfolder\pg_branchbuild\tests\sentinalonetests\bin\debug\netcoreapp2.0\sentinalonetests.dll" id="15590544-6d25-4b07-9736-91fc3089eb1d">
      <Execution id="49fb4bd0-d650-4ed4-b0f2-40241b138f40" />
      <TestMethod codeBase="C:\Jenkins\workspace\TestFolder\PG_BranchBuild\Tests\SentinaloneTests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\SentinaloneTests.dll" executorUriOfAdapter="executor://nunit3testexecutor/" className="SentinaloneTests.SentinaloneEngineConnectorTest" name="TestSentinalOneFullScanOfSingleFile_Success" />
    </UnitTest>
  </TestDefinitions>
  <TestEntries>
    <TestEntry testId="a08b2ec5-a68d-434b-a35f-6c65159eee8f" executionId="77a19978-2bbb-4bcb-afaa-d5be4384e0d1" testListId="8c84fa94-04c1-424b-9868-57a2d4851a1d" />
    <TestEntry testId="15590544-6d25-4b07-9736-91fc3089eb1d" executionId="49fb4bd0-d650-4ed4-b0f2-40241b138f40" testListId="8c84fa94-04c1-424b-9868-57a2d4851a1d" />
  </TestEntries>
  <TestLists>
    <TestList name="Results Not in a List" id="8c84fa94-04c1-424b-9868-57a2d4851a1d" />
    <TestList name="All Loaded Results" id="19431567-8539-422a-85d7-44ee4e166bda" />
  </TestLists>
  <ResultSummary outcome="Completed">
    <Counters total="2" executed="2" passed="2" failed="0" error="0" timeout="0" aborted="0" inconclusive="0" passedButRunAborted="0" notRunnable="0" notExecuted="0" disconnected="0" warning="0" completed="0" inProgress="0" pending="0" />
    <Output>
      <StdOut>NUnit Adapter 3.8.0.0: Test execution startedRunning all tests in C:\Jenkins\workspace\TestFolder\PG_BranchBuild\Tests\SentinaloneTests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\SentinaloneTests.dllNUnit3TestExecutor converted 2 of 2 NUnit test casesNUnit Adapter 3.8.0.0: Test execution complete</StdOut>
    </Output>
  </ResultSummary>
</TestRun>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also tried with:

```
step([$class: 'NUnitPublisher', testResultsPattern: 'Tests\\FilesScannerTests\\TestResults\\unit_tests.xml', debug: false, keepJUnitReports: true, skipJUnitArchiver:false, failIfNoResults: true])
```

But it didn't worked out as well..

Comment: I'm not familiar with Jenkins. But it looks like you're asking dotnet test for a trx file, and then then asking Jenkins to publish an NUnit-formatted file? My guess is that `nunit testResultsPattern...` needs to be changed to whatever the command is for publishing a trx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to do so using the "**MSTestPublisher**" class,

So the final pipeline is:

```html
node {
stage 'Checkout'
    checkout scm

stage 'Build'
    bat "\"C:/Program Files/dotnet/dotnet.exe\" restore \"${workspace}/MyProg.sln\""
    bat "\"C:/Program Files/dotnet/dotnet.exe\" build \"${workspace}/MyProg.sln\""

stage 'UnitTests'
    bat returnStatus: true, script: "\"C:/Program Files/dotnet/dotnet.exe\" test \"${workspace}/MyProg.sln\" --logger \"trx;LogFileName=unit_tests.xml\" --no-build"
    step([$class: 'MSTestPublisher', testResultsFile:"**/unit_tests.xml", failOnError: true, keepLongStdio: true])
}
```

I have uploaded some examples that I made to my GitHub for everyone to use and contribute, feel free to take a look:

https://github.com/avrum/JenkinsFileFor.NETCore

Those pipline jenkinsfile will add this pipline template to your build:

[image: Example Jenkins Pipeline|Solid]

Comment: @ Aviram: I am using the same stuff and logs are showing it is writing unit_test.xml log file also. But jenkins is not  recording the test results though , could you please advise what I am missing.                                         
      [MSTEST-PLUGIN] INFO processing test results in file(s) **/unit_tests.xml

Answer (score 0):

Jenkinsfile Declarative Pipeline

```
....
stages {
     stage('UnitTests') {
        steps {
            bat "nunit3-console.exe ${env.WORKSPACE}/<TestProject>/bin/Release/<TestProject>.dll --result=nunit3.xml"
        }
    }
}
post { 
    always {
         nunit testResultsPattern: 'nunit3.xml'
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure you can run .NetCoreApp with the nunit3-console I'm getting lots of exception like : Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.framework' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified,  and after publihshing the project "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutra
l, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system canno
t find the file specified."

Answer (score 0):

I have good results using the xUnit plugin (https://plugins.jenkins.io/xunit).

Run the tests generating *trx* output:

```
sh "dotnet test Tests/unit/ --logger:\"trx;LogFileName=results_Unit.testresults\""
sh "dotnet test Tests/Integration/ --logger:\"trx;LogFileName=results_Integration.testresults\""
```

And to publish run xUnit with *MSTest* and the pattern:

```
xunit([MSTest(deleteOutputFiles: true, failIfNotNew: true, pattern: '**/*.testresults', skipNoTestFiles: false, stopProcessingIfError: true)])
```

I use declarative syntax so I put this last step in a `post always` section. For example:

```
pipeline {
   agent any
   stages {
      stage('Build')
      {
         steps {
           sh "dotnet build"
         }
      }
      stage("run tests") {
         steps {
           sh "dotnet test Tests/unit/ --logger:\"trx:LogFileName=unit.testresults\""
         }
      }
   }
   post {
     always {
       xunit([MSTest(deleteOutputFiles: true, failIfNotNew: true, pattern: '**/*.testresults', skipNoTestFiles: false, stopProcessingIfError: true)])
     }
   }
}
```